# Can i add Flash to CEFSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, flash, cefsharp

i'm working on simple browser. And i want using modern browser(Webkit, geckofx and etc.) I deciced CEFSharp to use. But i want enable flash player. Or add. I know NPAPI disabled and using now PPAPI. But i don't know how add pepperflashplayer.dll. I tried specif path as CEFSharp setting for try add pepperflashplayer.dll. But this didn't work too. And i have looked some articles and questions but all of them didn't worked on my program. I'm using C# and i'm building it with WinForms. I'm beginner.
Anyone know how fixing this?

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Install the `System Wide` flash player, easiest option https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1505#issuecomment-166484362

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: Works for everyone else. Make sure you installed the `PPAPI` version,